# React - Object(...) is not a function or its return value is not iterable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a small React hook that is wrapping a class component and I am trying to pass a state from this hook to the class using `useEffect` but I keep getting the followwing error;

`TypeError: Object(...) is not a function or its return value is not iterable` on the following line;

`const [{}, dispatch] = useStateValue();`

I use the same line in another hook elsewhere in my app so I am not sure why this one is throwing this particular error

This is the complete component code.

If anyone has any ideas why this may not be working I would be most appreciative to hear them.

Thank you.

Component

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import App from 'next/app';

import firebase from 'firebase';

import { useStateValue, StateProvider } from '../state';
import { firebaseConfig } from '../constants';
import { initialState, reducer } from '../reducer';

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}

function AppWrapper(Component) {
    return function WrappedComponent(props) {
        const [{}, dispatch] = useStateValue();

        useEffect(() => {
            console.log('Moiunted');
            firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
                dispatch({
                    type: 'userLogin',
                    currentUser: user
                })
            });
        }), [];
        return <Component {...props} />
    }
}

class MyApp extends App {
    render() {
        const { Component, pageProps } = this.props;

        return (
            <StateProvider
                initialState={initialState}
                reducer={reducer}
            >
                <Component {...pageProps} />
            </StateProvider>
        );
    }
}
export default AppWrapper(MyApp)
```

State function

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useReducer } from 'react';

export const StateContext = createContext();

export const StateProvider = ({reducer, initialState, children}) => (
    <StateContext.Provider
        value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)}
    >
        {children}
    </StateContext.Provider>
);

export const useStateValue = () => useContext(StateContext);
```

Comment: If `useStateValue` does not return an array, the above error will be displayed

Comment: How to use **useState** it will more helpful [https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html]